# WSO2 - Default database configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I want to change the size of the default database in WSO2. I am using the Data Analytics Server and the database can only store until 100000 elements. I have been searching for this several days, but no solution found.

How can I configure the size of the database? Should I change the default one to another external one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean 100000 records? Even though H2 database is not preferred for higher environments, still it should work fine for most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong in my question! 100000 entries was not the limit in the event store, but the query result limit. Anyway, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use industry standard RDBMS such as Oracle, Mysql etc.
Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Working+with+Databases to configure an external database.